# cross table that counts unique values in R

Tags: r, count, crosstab

My data consists of 3 columns:
 - segment
 - category
 - product number

How can I create a cross tab ("**segment**" as columns, "**category**" as rows) that counts unique values of "**product number**" (example below) ?

```
      SEG1  SEG2  SEG3
CAT1   X
CAT2
CAT3
```

X - number of unique values from CAT1 and SEG1

**Exmple data**

```
CAT<-c("CAT1","CAT3","CAT3","CAT1","CAT2","CAT3","CAT3","CAT3","CAT3","CAT2") 
SEG<-c("SEG1","SEG3","SEG3","SEG2","SEG2","SEG2","SEG3","SEG3","SEG2","SEG2")   
PRODUCT<-c("a","a","a","a","d","e","b","c","a","a")
data<-cbind(CAT,SEG,PRODUCT)
```

Many thanks in advance !
Best regards,
Bartek

Comment: I need unique product numbers... :)

Comment: could you `dput` your data (or a sample of it)? so it would be easier to work on it

Comment: Sure, example below:

`CAT<-c("CAT1","CAT3","CAT3","CAT1","CAT2","CAT3","CAT3","CAT3","CAT3","CAT2")
SEG<-c("SEG1","SEG3","SEG3","SEG2","SEG2","SEG2","SEG3","SEG3","SEG2","SEG2")
PRODUCT<-c("a","a","a","a","d","e","b","c","a","a")
data<-cbind(CAT,SEG,PRODUCT)`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply compute a crosstable of your data but without duplicated lines to be sure to only count unique product numbers:

```
nodup <- which(!duplicated(data))
table(data[nodup, "CAT"],data[nodup, "SEG"])

       SEG1 SEG2 SEG3
  CAT1    1    1    0
  CAT2    0    2    0
  CAT3    0    2    3
```

Comment: That's a nice one but maybe create an index once instead of computing `duplicated(data)` twice?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a data.table, you could really speed the operation up for larger dataframes. You could use

```
    library(data.table)
    library(reshape)
    DF<-data.table(DF)
    DF_agg<-DF[,j=list(count_prod=length(unique(DF$Product_Number)),by=c("Segment","Category")]
    DF_agg<-cast(DF_agg,Segment~Category,sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

High speed solution with dplyr and tidyr packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


CAT <- c("CAT1","CAT3","CAT3","CAT1","CAT2","CAT3","CAT3","CAT3","CAT3","CAT2") 
SEG <- c("SEG1","SEG3","SEG3","SEG2","SEG2","SEG2","SEG3","SEG3","SEG2","SEG2")   
PRODUCT <- c("a","a","a","a","d","e","b","c","a","a")
data <- data.frame(CAT, SEG, PRODUCT)

# Elegant solution with pipes (%>%)
data %>% 
  group_by(CAT, SEG) %>%  
  summarize(uni.prod = n_distinct(PRODUCT)) %>%  
  spread(CAT, uni.prod)

# Solution without use pipes
groups <- group_by(data, CAT, SEG)
s <- summarize(groups, uni.prod = n_distinct(PRODUCT))
spread(s, CAT, uni.prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> set.seed(1)
> mydf <- data.frame(
+     Values = rep(c("111", "222", "333"), times = c(5, 3, 2)),
+     Year = c(rep(c("1999", "2000"), times = c(3, 2)), 
+            "1999", "1999", "2000", "2000", "2000"),
+     Month = sample(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), 10, replace = TRUE)
+ )
> mydf
   Values Year Month
1     111 1999   Jan
2     111 1999   Feb
3     111 1999   Feb
4     111 2000   Mar
5     111 2000   Jan
6     222 1999   Mar
7     222 1999   Mar
8     222 2000   Feb
9     333 2000   Feb
10    333 2000   Jan
> with(mydf, tapply(Month, list(Values, Year), FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))
    1999 2000
111    2    2
222    1    1
333   NA    2
>
```

For your example:

```
> data
    CAT  SEG PRODUCT
1  CAT1 SEG1       a
2  CAT3 SEG3       a
3  CAT3 SEG3       a
4  CAT1 SEG2       a
5  CAT2 SEG2       d
6  CAT3 SEG2       e
7  CAT3 SEG3       b
8  CAT3 SEG3       c
9  CAT3 SEG2       a
10 CAT2 SEG2       a
> with(data, tapply(PRODUCT, list(CAT, SEG), FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))
     SEG1 SEG2 SEG3
CAT1    1    1   NA
CAT2   NA    2   NA
CAT3   NA    2    3
```

Comment: Thank you. I was really close ! Have a nice day !

Comment: @haver24 accept this a solution, if it solves purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
data <- data.frame(data)
a <- ddply(data,.(CAT,SEG),summarize,unq=length(unique(PRODUCT)))
b <- cast(a,CAT~SEG,mean)
```

This will generate NaN at places where the count of unique values = 0

Answer (score 0):

A couple more suggestions if your data is in a data frame. Can use `dplyr::n_distinct` instead of `n_unique` as defined below.

```
data = data.frame(
  CAT = factor(CAT),
  SEG = factor(SEG),
  PRODUCT = as.character(PRODUCT)
)

n_unique <- function(x) length(unique(x))
```

Using base R

```
dat_counts <- aggregate(PRODUCT ~ CAT + SEG, data = data, FUN = n_unique)
xtabs(PRODUCT ~ CAT + SEG, data = dat_counts)
```

Using the tables package. Note, the grouping variables (CAT and SEG) need to be factors, and the value variable (PRODUCT) needs to be a character variable.

```
tables::tabular(
  CAT ~ SEG * PRODUCT * n_unique
  , data = data)
```

These are fine for small datasets, but the other approaches are faster for larger datasets.